# Angular2 - having trouble using router method in model

Tags: angular

Im trying to trigger a method in my model using angular router, i have seperated my model from the the component view. Here is my component:

```
// we also need the Input module
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

// Our model
import { ArchiveProduct } from './archive-product.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-archive-product',
  templateUrl: './archive-product.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./archive-product.component.css']
})
export class ArchiveProductComponent implements OnInit {

  // input variables from archiveProduct and match them to the ArchiveProduct model
  @Input() archiveProduct: ArchiveProduct;

  selectPost(): any {
    this.archiveProduct.selectPost();
  }      
  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

And here is my model:

```
// Exports a class of ArchiveProduct
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

export class ArchiveProduct {

  // declare our props
  title: string;
  id: number;
  slug: string;

  // constructor
  constructor(title: string, id: number, slug: string, private router: Router ) {
    this.title = title;
    this.id = id;
    this.slug = slug;
  }

  selectPost(slug) {
    this.router.navigate([this.slug]);
  }

}
```

At the moment I am a 'Supplied parametersdo not match any signature or target' error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the wrong function name, you are calling the function `selectPost` that doesn't exist in `ArchiveProduct` it should be `selectProduct`.

Incorrect

```
  selectPost(): any {
    this.archiveProduct.selectPost();
  }
```

Correct

```
  selectPost(): any {
    this.archiveProduct.selectProduct();
  }
```

Comment: My bad that was a typo, I do have the correct function names in my actual code. Im still getting the 'Supplied parameters' error, any ideas?

Comment: Can you supply the template and the component that uses ArchiveProductComponent?

Answer (score 0):

1) Your code of selectPost in ArchiveProduct is

```
  selectPost(slug) {
    this.router.navigate([this.slug]);
  }
```

so it has input parameter. In TypeScript, every parameter is assumed to be required by the function.
But you call it in ArchiveProductComponent without parameters like that:

```
  selectPost(): any {
    this.archiveProduct.selectPost();
  }
```

2) Note that selectPost in ArchiveProduct

```
  selectPost(slug) {
    this.router.navigate([this.slug]);
  }
```

pass `this.slug` into navigate method instead of parameter `slug`.

Answer (score 0):

Hey all what I ended up realising was that the selectPost method that I was calling was operating from the ArchiveProductComponent class. So all I did was move the selectPost method into archive-product.component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

import { Router } from '@angular/router';

// Our model
import { ArchiveProduct } from './archive-product.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-archive-product',
  templateUrl: './archive-product.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./archive-product.component.css']
})
export class ArchiveProductComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }
  // input variables from archiveProduct and match them to the ArchiveProduct model
  @Input() archiveProduct: ArchiveProduct;

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  selectPost(slug) {
    let route = 'product/' + slug;
    this.router.navigate([route]);
  }

}
```